# How to fix ''AttributeError: module 'pyglet.text' has no attribute 'label'" error in python

Tags: python, pyglet

I am attempting to create a simple game with pyglet. I am still learning this library and am using the pyglet Programming guide to learn. However, I get the

> AttributeError: module 'pyglet.text' has no attribute 'label'

error every time I run the code.

I have tried `import pyglet.text` and `import pyglet.text.label`. `import pyglet.text` still gives

> AttributeError: module 'pyglet.text' has no attribute 'label'.

However, `import pyglet.text.label` gives

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyglet.text.label'.

My code is:

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.text.label

window = pyglet.window.Window()
label = pyglet.text.label('Hello World',
    font_name='Times New Roman',
    font_size=36,
    x=window.width//2,
    y=window.height//2,
    anchor_x='center',
    anchor_y='center')
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
pyglet.app.run()
```

I expected to see the window cleared to the default background color with Hello World printed on-screen. But I always get a blank window with

> AttributeError: module 'pyglet.text' has no attribute 'label'

printed in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AttributeError: module 'pyglet.text' has no attribute 'label'
```

You are getting this error because you are using `pyglet.text.label` instead of  `pyglet.text.Label`.

Here is the documentation to [`text`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/modules/text/index.html?highlight=pyglet.text)

Import only pyglet then change label to Label and it should work.

Comment: Are all attributes similar in that you need to capitalize the first letter? (ex: `pyglet.resource.Image` instead of `pyglet.resource.image`)

Comment: That depends on the module and the function you are trying to access. You can lookup pyglet documentation to make sure you are using the right syntax. AttributeError happens when you are trying to access something that doesn't exist.